# Windows Phone 7 ProgressBar color of the incomplete part

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, progress-bar

I'm using a determinate ProgressBar control to indicate completeness of a block in ListView (for example the amount of points scored in a level compared to the maximum.

I can change the Foreground property of the progress bar to change color of the "completed" part of the bar, but I cannot alter color of the incomplete part of the bar.

For example, if Value is 5, Maximum is 20, and Width is 100 px, then color of line from 0 to 25 would be Red, and the color of line from 25 to 100 is what I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the colour slightly by setting the Background property of the ProgressBar control. If you do this you will see the colour of the incomplete part being a shade of the colour you define due to some opacity being set on the incomplete part. If you want a solid colour rather than a colour with opacity set then you will have to look at altering the style of the control itself.

If you open your page in Expression Blend, and then Right Click on the ProgressBar control and select Edit Template > Edit a Copy... then a new style will be created. The part of the Style you are looking to edit is as follows :-

```
<Rectangle x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="4" Opacity="0.1"/>
```

If you alter the Opacity value or remove it all together then a solid colour will be allowed.